# How to use @Parcelize in Kotlin 1.1.60?

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable, parcel

Kotlin 1.1.60 is recently out with the [Parcelable support](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/11/kotlin-1-1-60-is-out/).

With this new feature, I created my data as:

```
@Parcelize 
data class Question {
   val id: String,
   val title: String,
   val detail: String
} : Parcelable
```

But this raise an error of *This class implements Parcelable but does not provide a CREATOR field*.

It seems like I still have to write tedious code to implement Parcel data, if so, what's the benefit of using `@Parcelize` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say this feature is still experimental. What you describe is a known bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19300

But it should not be preventing the code from being compiled as expected (try disregarding the warning and see if your code works as expected).

Comment: I tried `getParcelableExtra("question")` and ran the app, it works fine. However, it did raise the error: *Class not found when unmarshalling:...*